# Equivalent metrics on Product topology

Tags: general-topology

[Metrics defined On product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HRpw.jpg)

Can we say that this two metrics defined on countable product is equivalent? If so, how can I start? Because the second one is I guess for the Baire(ω^ω) space producing the topology of it

Comment: The metrics $d$ and $d^*$ generate the same topology on the product if and only if the spaces $X_i$ are discrete.

Comment: So if I take each X_{i}=N with discrete topology, it works?

Comment: Yes, if you do that, then both metrics yield the product topology, and you get the Baire space.

Comment: Thank you so much, so last one question, each ρ-i is metric bounded by 1, also each N is discrete, how Can I find the relation between them? I have two metrics on each N then?

Comment: You can use any metrics $\rho_i$ that are bounded by $1$ and generate the discrete topology on $X_i=\Bbb N$; I would simply use the discrete metric, so that $\rho_i(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$ and $0$ if $x=y$.

Comment: thank you so much I am greatful

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Comment: is There any more hint about showing this equivalence? I tried so hard but I could not, If you help me a bit, I would be very happy

Comment: on any Xi with discrete metric